# Blogger page like contact us Display Content on Half of the Page

Tags: html

This page https://affliates2.blogspot.com/p/blog-page.html  is my contact us page only displays content in  right half of the page on mobile but it appear properly on desktop.

It  display their content in only half of the page while leaving the other half blank on all screen sizes. I have tweaked my HTML source code and couldn't get what's causing this.

I am using a responsive template,  I'm confused why this error should occur.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Because you have media query which works on viewport width < 760px (mobile)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .post {
     width: 41%
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .post {
     width: 28.5%
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .post {
     width: 29%
   }
}
```

Just remove this css selectors and page will look fine
[image]

Comment: would you please show me in html code which part i should remove exactly because i am not expert

Comment: my proplem for contact us solved but thumbnail in main page on mobile appear smaller this happend after i removed css codes u gave to me previously please help me to figure this out